# Почему слайдер swiper.js перелистывает при клике на слайд?

Tags: javascript, swiper

У меня есть слайдер, внутри каждого слайда есть кнопка и ссылка и при клике на кнопку слайдер перелистывает на следующий слайд. Если я правильно поняла это связано с событием клика и его всплытием. В документации библиотеки есть два свойства которые должны запрещать это перелистывание. Одно это noSwipingClass (при добавлении класса 'swiper-no-swiping' на кнопку должно перестать перелистывать), но для меня это не работает, второе это noSwipingSelector (нужно в инициализацию слайдера добавить этот ключ со значением тега, в моем случае кнопки) но и это не фурычит. Я что-то не так делаю? Кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой?

https://codepen.io/YanaE93/pen/xxpBypQ

```
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {navigation: {nextEl:'.swiper-button-next',prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',},slidesPerView: 3,spaceBetween: 30,noSwipingClass: 'swiper-no-swiping',noSwipingSelector: 'button',});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Вдруг кому-то поможет для меня сработало добавить

watchSlidesProgress: true

Comment: Сестра, столкнулся с той же проблемой
Спасибо, мне тоже помогло)
Ты сэкономила мне кучу времени, ещё раз - спасибо огромнейшее))